# Can't print the result of POSTing all files in a folder in Python?

Tags: python, python-requests, glob

I have a Python script that tries to POST all the files in a certain directory with the extension ".csv" to a URL, and then print the result (using Requests and Glob):

```
import requests, glob


text_files = glob.iglob("./user/Documents/folder/folder/*.csv")


url = 'http://myWebsite.com/extension/extension/extension'

for data in text_files:
    current_file = open(data)
    r = requests.post(url, files=current_file)
    print r.text
```

However, nothing is printed, even though POSTing the same files in Terminal via cURL produces an output specific to the server. I can't figure out why but am guessing that I'm somehow implementing glob incorrectly.

Comment: Maybe you need to read the file? So it should be `r = requests.post(url, files=current_file.read())`.

Comment: There is *nothing* printed? No error messages? What does `print r` print?

Comment: @joemar.ct: no, you can give `requests` an open file object.

Comment: If you think that you use glob incorrectly why not print text_files first.

Comment: Did you mean to look for files relative to the current working directory? What *is* the current working directory when you run this? Most likely `text_files` is an empty list.

Comment: How do I know what the current working directory is? I didn't know that mattered, I just want to reference the directory specified in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed via trial and error. I apologize if I incorrectly answer my own question (as far as etiquette is concerned, that is) and will try to give credit where it is necessary. Credit to @Martijn Pieters for suggesting that something was wrong with the path to the directory. Went to where the .csv files are and got the path to them manually via "get info" (I'm on a MAC). The correct path should have been:

```
/Users/ME/Documents/folder/folder/*.csv
```

Also `current_file = open(data)` should be replaced with `current_file = {'file': open(data)}` The problem here is that Python doesn't know that "data" *is* a file and will throw a plethora of errors. New code:

```
import requests, glob

text_files = glob.iglob("/Users/ME/Documents/folder/folder/*.csv")

url = 'http://myWebsite.com/extension/extension/extension'

for data in text_files:
    with open(data) as f:
        file2 = {'file': f}
        r = requests.post(url, files=file2)
    print r.text
```

Comment: Good it works now. Programming is iterative process as you see. Try one iteration more and handle closing open file descriptor. Your current `open(data)` opens a file and it gets closed sometime later at the moment, garbage collection will find good time to clean unreferenced file descriptor. This might generate problems, if you would need to work with the same file from another place.

Comment: Good idea, I will implement this ASAP. Sorry, I'm a Python noob and don't know much about opening/closing files.

Answer (score 0):

The reason nothing is printed is simple

You are posting the file up, it gets posted, but is there any script on the server side which would necessarily generate any response text?

Probably the script on server side simply accepts the file and by responding HTTP 200 OK tells you that all is fine. Note, that HTTP 200 OK is not part of `r.text`

Do simple test: post the file from command line using `curl` or post just one file by requests and see, if there is really some response. It is likely, there is (naturally) no response text.

Btw, you shall care about closing your files after you open them:

```
for data in text_files:
    with open(data) as current_file:
        r = requests.post(url, files=current_file)
    print r.text
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion but running the same command in Terminal does produce a specific output. I apologize for not having specified this in the question. It has been edited.